# Pass an array of pointers to function argument

Tags: c, pointers, graph, dynamic-arrays, adjacency-list

I am trying to construct a bus network using adjacent linked list graph data structure.
A simplified code is shown below:

```
typedef struct BusNetwork
{
    struct AdjStopList *stopsArray;  //defing the array of pointers
} BusNetwork;

typedef struct Node
{
    int stopID;
    struct Node *next;
} Node;

typedef struct AdjStopList
{
    char stopName[20];
    int numOfAdjStp;
    struct Node *first;
} AdjStopList;

void insertStopAtLast(AdjStopList *L, int stopID)
{
    //add stopID to the last node of the list
    return;
}

void addBusRoute(AdjStopList *L[], int from, int to)
{
    if (from == to)
        return;

    insertStopAtLast(L[from], to);
    return;
}

void main(BusNetwork *BN, int from, int to)
{
    addBusRoute(BN->stopsArray, from, to);
}
```

The problem is with `addBusRoute(BN->stopsArray, from, to);` It seems I didn't pass the same type of value as function argument. But my understanding of `BN->stopsArray` is an array of pointers, which should be the same as `AdjStopList L[]`. What went wrong?

Comment: The signature of `main` is not legal.

Comment: I guess the `stopsArray` member should be declared `struct AdjStopList **stopsArray;  //defing the array of pointers` since that matches the comment and the call `addBusRoute(BN->stopsArray, from, to);`. However, I have no idea what `BN->stopsArray` is *really* pointing to in your code because it is incomplete. Your understanding of `BN->stopsArray` as an array of pointers in your original code is incorrect - it is a pointer to a `struct AdjStopList`. It can be used to point to an element of an array of `struct AdjStopList` and access all the elements of that array by indexing.

Comment: I see. I guess if I wanted to avoid using double pointer. I could define another struct say`typedef struct stopsArray{
    struct BusAtStopList *array;
} stopsArray;` Then in my `BusNetwork`, I can have a pointer to `stopsArray`.?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid a double pointer?

Comment: Shamefully speaking....double-pointer is just too confusing to me

Answer (score 1):

The argument `AdjStopList *L[]` has the same meaning as `AdjStopList **L`.

On the other hand, what is passed `BN->stopsArray` is `struct AdjStopList *`.

The argument is a pointer to *a pointer to* `AdjStopList`, but what is passed is a pointer to `AdjStopList`.

Therefore, the type differs.

Comment: Thanks Mike. I see what you mean So how can I pass the ` BN->stopsArray` to the function argument? I have tried to change `BN->stopsArray` to `BN.stopsArray`. Could you please give me some more hints?

Comment: `&BN->stopsArray` will be accepted by the compiler, but this looks weird because this is seeing that as one-element array while `addBusRoute` looks like designed for multiple-element array being passed. This looks like the definition of `struct BusNetwork` is wrong, but I cannot say definitely without the context.

Comment: I have thought about this and tried `&(BN->stopsArray)`, I wonder if they are the same? So my idea is, each element of the array stores a specific bus route. And `int from` of `addBusRoute` indicates which bus route (which is the index of the array) needs to extend further, of which the extended distance is defined by `int to`. Apologies if it confuses you